# Regex is not validation string

Tags: regex, vb.net

Hi I have below regular expression which I am using to validate string expression:

```
Regex: ^\d{9}_[a-zA-Z]{1}_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}(?:_[0-9a-zA-Z]*)?

String :999999999_A_12.31.2015_000_3Q_cdvknv
```

What i was expecting is if user enters below string it should not match with my regular expression:

```
String :999999999_A_12.31.2015_000_3Qwe_cdvknv
```

But instead of showing as wrong form it was checking for match case i tried using online validator but couldn't find correct one. Please suggest. I am using vb.net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can solve the issue by adding an anchor:

```
^\d{9}_[a-zA-Z]_(0[1-9]|1[0-2]).(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1]).[0-9]{4}_[0-9]{3}_[0-9a-zA-Z]{2}(?:_[0-9a-zA-Z]*)?$
                                                                                                             ^
```

See [demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5cd%7b9%7d_%5ba-zA-Z%5d_(0%5b1-9%5d%7c1%5b0-2%5d).(0%5b1-9%5d%7c%5b1-2%5d%5b0-9%5d%7c3%5b0-1%5d).%5b0-9%5d%7b4%7d_%5b0-9%5d%7b3%7d_%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d%7b2%7d(%3f%3a_%5b0-9a-zA-Z%5d*)%3f%5cr%3f%24&i=999999999_A_12.31.2015_000_3Q_cdvknv%0d%0a999999999_A_12.31.2015_000_3Qwe_cdvknv&o=m)

The `$` is an end-of-string anchor and will force the string to end after `3Q`. If there are any more characters but not `_xxx`, the match will fail.

Note that if you need to check for a partial match inside a larger sentence, you might as well use `\b` word boundary instead of `$`.

And note that `{1}` is redundant.

Comment: Please also consider upvoting (the up arrow on the left) if you found my answer helfpul.